# ¿Como devuelvo la diferencia de dos fechas con GregorianCalendar? Dadas en dias

Tags: java

Estoy intentando hacer una actividad en Java, y estoy revisando la clase de GregorianCalendar y necesito comparar 2 fechas, y que me devuelva los días que hay de una a otra.

He visto el método .compareTo, pero solo me ha funcionado con la clase Date o LocalDate. Con Gregorian siempre me devuelve un 1 o un -1.

¿Alguna forma simple de hacerlo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

usando GregorianCalendar se me ocurre creando un metodo propio, espero te sirva

```
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;
import java.util.Date;

public class Test{

    public static int daysBetween(Date d1, Date d2){
             return (int)( (d2.getTime() - d1.getTime()) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
     }

    public static void main(String [] args){
        Calendar fecha1 = new GregorianCalendar(2019, Calendar.FEBRUARY, 10);
        Calendar fecha2 = new GregorianCalendar(2019, Calendar.FEBRUARY, 12);
        int dias = daysBetween(fecha1.getTime(),fecha2.getTime());


        System.out.println(dias);
    }

}
```

Comment: Buenas! si me ha servido muchas gracias. Le he dado un par de retoques para ajustarlo a mi código, y perfecto :)